# Can't bind the content of a contentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I can't figure out what I'm missing here. I want to bind the content of a ContentPresenter to a UIElement. I'm doing something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="container">
        <Border>
            <!--<TextBlock Text="A"/>-->
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Element}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource container}" />
```

In MainWindow.cs

```
UIElement Element { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    Element = new TextBox() { Text = "A" };
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I can put the textBlock in directly, but when I try the ContentPresenter it does not display anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ContentTemplate` is a template for *content*. So, in the case of `ContentControl`, `Content` becomes `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate`. But you can't set `Window` as `Content` and the property you bind to has to be public.

So, after making `Element` public property and changing the XAML to:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="container">
        <Border>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Element}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource container}" />
```

“A” is shown in the window.

I'm assuming this isn't the real code where you encountered the issue, but doing something like this looks very odd. Maybe you should rethink your design.

Comment: Well put! First issue is 'Element' was not public. Second issue is that The ContentControl had no 'Content' and therefore the ContentTemplate had no content to use the template.